# Discord Python Rewrite - wait_for('reaction_add')

Tags: discord, discord.py

so, im trying to make a reaction help with this code

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("Eh idk just react")

    await msg.add_reaction("⬅️")
    await msg.add_reaction("➡️")

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ['⬅️', '➡️']

    try:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=5, check=check)
    
        if reaction == '➡️':
            await ctx.send("NEEXT!")
            return

        elif reaction == '⬅️':
            await ctx.send("RETUUURN!")
            return

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Timed out")
```

but when a reaction added, it dosen't do anything. Can someone help me? I want reaction help for 1week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`reaction.emoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Reaction.emoji) when comparing to unicode emojis.

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("Eh idk just react")

    await msg.add_reaction("⬅️")
    await msg.add_reaction("➡️")

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ['⬅️', '➡️']

    try:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=5, check=check)
    
        if reaction.emoji == '➡️':
            await ctx.send("NEEXT!")
            return

        elif reaction.emoji == '⬅️':
            await ctx.send("RETUUURN!")
            return

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Timed out")
```